# React "export default" stateless component issue

Tags: reactjs

Why would this work:

```
const PostComponent = ({post}) => (
  <span>
      <div>{post.text}</div>
  </span>
)

export default PostComponent;
```

And not this:

```
export default PostComponent = ({post}) => (
  <span>
      <div>{post.text}</div>
  </span>
)
```

The later says the component is undefined when imported.

Comment: Because `PostComponent` is not defined. And you can't define and export at once with default export. `export default function({post}) { ... }` is possible however.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dfsq already answered in comments, and just to let you know, this will work

```
export default ({post}) => (
  <span>
      <div>{post.text}</div>
  </span>
)
```

but doing this, the component will be anonymous. If you have React devtool installed, you will just see `StatelessComponent`

[image]